Azure ADF: Losing Value of Pipeline Variable when re-running an Activity
In ADF, I have a demo pipeline with three activities and one pipeline variable called parentRunId:
pipeline variable

The first activity is a "Set Variable" activity and generates a UUID for parentRunId:
supply variable with UUID:

The second activity uses parentRunId to pass it to a Databricks notebook:
pass variable to notebook:

The third step is irrelevant for this example.
This all works, and the UUID is displayed in my Databrick notebook.
But I want to be able to restart my pipeline from step 2, in case it failed.
So I select the "Rerun from selected activity" button in the ADF monitor on the second step:
rerun from selected activity

My expectation would be, that the variable parentRunId is still the same (because I am not re-running the first step, which would generate the UUID).
However, surprisingly, a new UUID is generated and passed to Databricks.
This makes it difficult for me to recover from a failure, because the pipeline seemingly has lost its context.
Is this a bug? Any idea how I can pass on a piece of information between activities which will also be reliably available when I restart in the middle of the pipeline?


Is this a bug? Any idea how I can pass on a piece of information between activities which will also be reliably available when I restart in the middle of the pipeline?

I think this is a default nature in ADF that set variable activities will be executed again whenever we re-run the pipeline even though it says skipped.
To achieve your requirement, you can try the below workaround. But for this, you need a Blob storage or ADLS storage, copy activity and a lookup activity.
During the re-run, the copy activity and lookup activities will be skipped. So, first store the run_id in a file using copy activity and then get it using lookup activity.
Follow the below design.

create a dummy source.csv file with one and one column in ADLS or Blob. Create dataset for that and add as source for the copy activity. In the source, add your run_id variable to the source by creating additional column for it like above.
Copy this to another csv file. Add that dataset to the copy activity sink.

Now, take a lookup activity with same target dataset like below.

At the first pipeline run, the copy activity will create an additional column for the run_id and stores it in the target csv file. The lookup activity will give the required run_id from the same target dataset.
You can use the below expression to get that from lookup.
@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].run_id

Instead of Notebook activity, here I am using a set variable activity to get that.

Normal pipeline run:

The above pipeline run_id will be stored in the file.
Here, I am re-running the Set variable2 activity.

Required old pipeline run_id:

Even though the new pipeline run_id got stored in the first activity, you can see it gave the required old pipeline run_id.
Just replace the last activity with your notebook activity and pass the same expression to your notebook activity parameter.

Thanks a lot for your extensive answer. Unfortunately I could not make it work yet (somehow the run_id does not get written into the file), but I have a general concern with this solution: What if this pipeline is triggered several times in parallel (e.g. triggered by arriving files) - wouldn't the run_id in the file be overwritten and thus become useless?

Yes, in that case, this solution won't work. It will only work in the case of sequential pipeline runs. I thought you are only re-running the failed pipeline run. If there is no failure, it will work even in the parallel runs, but in the case of re-running of failed pipeline run in parallel runs, it might not work.

Yes I did not make it clear in the initial post: The pipeline is a generic file handler which can run in parallel.
